# Load another deployed contract's public values

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

I'm trying to call another contract's functions to return values.

I have the below which successfully returns a true/false

```
_childAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("isValidChild(uint256, uint256)")), _childModule6, 6) == true)
```

But when I try to return an actual value like so:

```
uint256 tokenId = _childAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("totalSupply()")));
```

I get the following error:

Type bool is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
tokenId

I can't find the syntax anywhere for returning a value.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should share the relevant code of each one of these contracts, since no one here can guess what it is!

Comment: add more code please, and use truffle, cause remix does not work always as expected

Answer (score 1):

With solc v0.5 the signature of `call` changed it returns a tuple `(bool, bytes)`. The first parameter indicates if the call successful and the second parameter is the result of the function.

```
    bool success;
    bytes memory result;
    uint totalSupply;
```

Make the call using `abi.encodeWithSignature` to encode parameters and function signature

```
    (success, result) = childContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("totalSupply()"));
    if (success) {
```

If the call was successful decode the result of the function

```
        (totalSupply) = abi.decode(result, (uint));
        return totalSupply;
    }
```

With v0.4 either you create an interface for your child contract or use assemply to obtain the value returned by the call.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, and also widely used. however if you do a `address.call` the compiler will not allow to mark the function as `view` even if you're just reading the value. That's because `address.call` could be used to write the state as well.

if you want a `view` function with a low level call to `totalSupply()` do this

```
function readTotalSupply() external view returns(uint) {
    (, bytes memory data) = childContract.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("totalSupply()"));
    return abi.decode(data, (uint));
}
```